# Magento rest api resources

Tags: api, rest, magento

I have an android application connected to magento server by rest api. The application must preform some actions, but I have no examples of requests needed for the application.

For example I have this [list of requests](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resources.html), but it is superficial enough for my application. For example, I do request:
"http://myUrl.com/api/rest/products?limit=15" and receive the list of 15 products. But after I need to receive next 15 product, and next, and next... What request can do it?
Also I need to do another requests which have no in site examples.
Where can I get more information and examples about rest api requests? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various get filters available for REST request in magento [GET FILTERS](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/get_filters.html). To access second page you can use page filter available i.e. "http://myUrl.com/api/rest/products?limit=15&page=2". You can also combine many filters and use them as you want. Eg. For getting a result of products which have their name like 'product123', you can use: **magentohost/api/rest/products?filter[1][attribute]=name&filter[1][like]=%product123%**.